# Hide several divs and only after all are hidden, then run a callback function

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am needing to hide all of the divs of class .panel in a container div.  Then after all are hidden, selectively unhide a few of the .panel divs.  I tried using a callback on hide() but the callback runs for every single element that is hidden.  In some cases I end up in a nearly infinite or long running loop as the same divs are hidden and shown over and over.

This does not work as the second elements are being shown before the hide is complete:

```
$("#detailsPanel").children(".panel").hide();
$("#membershipPanel").slideDown();
$("#specializationsPanel").slideDown();
```

And if I nest those steps after the hide in a callback, the call back runs for every .panel div that is hidden.

---

**FULL CODE**

Here is my full function if that helps to find the flaw in my logic.

```
function goWizard(step) {
    switch (step) {
        case 0:
            $("#formPanel").hide();
            $("#beginPanel").slideDown();
            $("#instructionsPanel").slideDown().children().slideDown();
            $("#loginPanel").slideDown().children().slideDown();
            break;
        case 1:
            $("#beginPanel").hide().children().hide();
            $("#stepTitle").text("Membership Category/Specialist Category :: Step 1 of 8");
            $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "slow");
            $("#summaryPanel").slideDown().children().show();
            $("#formPanel").slideDown();

            var i = 0;
            var $panels = $("#detailsPanel").children(".panel");
            $panels.hide(function () {
                i++;
                if (i == $panels.length) {
                    $("#membershipPanel").show();
                    $("#specializationsPanel").show();
                }
            });

            $("#startOverButton").show();
            $("#prevStepButton").hide();
            $("#nextStepButton").show();
            $("#startOverButton").click(function () { goWizard(0); });
            $("#nextStepButton").click(function () { goWizard(2); });
            break;
        case 2:
            $("#beginPanel").hide().children().hide();
            $("#stepTitle").text("Section Membership :: Step 2 of 8");
            $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "slow");
            $("#summaryPanel").slideDown().children().show();
            $("#formPanel").slideDown();

            var i = 0;
            var $panels = $("#detailsPanel").children(".panel");
            $panels.hide(function () {
                i++;
                if (i == $panels.length) {
                    $("#sectionsPanel").show();
                }
            });

            $("#startOverButton").hide();
            $("#prevStepButton").show();
            $("#nextStepButton").show();
            $("#prevStepButton").click(function () { goWizard(1); });
            $("#nextStepButton").click(function () { goWizard(3); });
            break;
        case 3:
            $("#beginPanel").hide().children().hide();
            $("#stepTitle").text("Insurance Compliance :: Step 3 of 8");
            $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "slow");
            $("#summaryPanel").slideDown().children().show();
            $("#formPanel").slideDown();

            var i = 0;
            var $panels = $("#detailsPanel").children(".panel");
            $panels.hide(function () {
                i++;
                if (i == $panels.length) {
                    $("#insurancePanel").show();
                }
            });

            $("#startOverButton").hide();
            $("#prevStepButton").show();
            $("#nextStepButton").show();
            $("#prevStepButton").click(function () { goWizard(2); });
            $("#nextStepButton").click(function () { goWizard(4); });
            break;
        default:
            $("#beginPanel").slideDown();
            $("#formPanel").hide();
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: `hide().children().hide()`and `.slideDown().children().show();` has no sense

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use promises:

```
$.when(
    $("#detailsPanel").children(".panel").hide().promise(),
    $("#membershipPanel").slideDown().promise(),
    $("#specializationsPanel").slideDown().promise()
).done(function() {
    console.log('all done');
});
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/jjh65h2y/

Comment: I like your solution better. Originally included promises in my example but not done as neatly as yours, nor was I able to test. +1!

Answer (score 0):

You could modify your `hide` callback to check if the element being hidden is the last one, and then do the callback in that portion, like so...

```
var i = 0;
var $panels = $("#detailsPanel").children(".panel");
$panels.hide(function() {

    i++;
    if(i == $panels.length) {
        $("#membershipPanel").slideDown();
        $("#specializationsPanel").slideDown();
    }

});
```

Comment: Thanks @guedes. Edited :)

Comment: This looks like it would work and sort of does, but as I move back and forth in my steps (using this for a basic wizard form), something is still not right.  For example, the membershipPanel is shown on step 1, go to step 2 then 3, then back to step 2 and the panels from step 1 appear.

Comment: I feel as though the issue you describe has to be unrelated to the snippet I've provided, and sounds more like how you're invoking the method. The snippet above simply hides all panels, and then shows the specifically-targeted two. Given that you've only now provided the full scope, I am not sure I would still suggest my solution.

Comment: @ConnieDeCinko I think your actuall question doesn't suit the real needs of  your expected output, try to clarify....seen your code seems like you are hardcoding all and can be reduced to one simple function whitout all those id's

Comment: I threw an alert in at the top and discovered that each time I click the button, I am adding another function to my next step button instead of replacing the existing function!  Doh!  How can I replace the function on my next page button?

Comment: Ok, if I use unbind on the button and then reattach the function to the click event, now, my steps code only fires once for each button press.  Whew!

Answer (score 0):

Given a DOM structure like (example):

```
<div class="panel">text</div>
<div class="panel unhide">text</div>
<div class="panel">text</div>
<div class="panel unhide">text</div>
<div class="panel">text</div>
```

You can hide and then unhide the elements in 2 ways with jQuery.

Either:

```
$.when($('.panel').animate({opacity: 0}, 500)).then(function () {
  $('.unhide').animate({opacity: 1}, 500);
});
```

Or:

```
$('.panel').animate({opacity: 0}, 500).promise().done(function () {
  $('.unhide').animate({opacity: 1}, 500);
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/q2mctsz6/